# The difference between "ante" and "antequam"

Tags: preposition, adverb

Not sure I can discern the crux of the difference between *antequam* and *ante* (According to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dante) (II.B.1.a vs II.B.2), *ante* might be used with verbs, like *antequam*). In other words, **in what occasions we are bound to use only one of them?** — when they are not simply interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *ante* is both a preposition and an adverb, whereas *antequam* is only an adverb — or more accurately *antequam* falls under the adverbial use types of *ante* and *antequam* is essentially a conjunction.
If you need a preposition, *ante* is your only option.
If you need an adverb, the difference between the two is small.

In [L&S both words are given under *ante*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D55%3Aentry%3Dante), with *antequam* only appearing in part II in adverbial usage, mostly in II.B.2.

I will let the details of this difference be fleshed out in possible other answers, because I just wanted to give this one point.

Comment: I would say *ante( )quam* is used as a conjunction, just like *quam*.

Comment: @Cerberus It seems that L&S (I added a link and some coordinates to my answer) that usage is classified as adverbial. I wonder if that dictionary makes a distinction between adverbs and conjunctions in any meaningful way.

Comment: It could be argued that many conjunctions have adverbial properties 'externally', since they head adverbial clauses ("because I like you"; "before she left"). The same can be said about many prepositions, which head adverbial phrases when combined with objects ("in the oven"; "before the war"). The word *ante* as used in combination with *quam* may be considered adverbial, which is no doubt why Lewis & Short mention it under adverbial; but the combination functions like a conjunction, does it not? When written as one word, certainly it must be a conjunction?

Comment: @Cerberus Agreed. I updated the answer slightly. I'd be happy to see more details in another answer.